# « Tu veux étudier quoi » est-il correct ?

Tags: usage, pronoms, questions, pronoms-interrogatifs

Aujourd'hui j'étais en train de parler avec une amie française et elle me dit :

> Tu veux étudier quoi ?

Ça fait étrange pour moi. Je pensais que *quoi* est pour se référer à des personnes et *que* à des choses.

Je dirais :

> Qu'est-ce que tu veux étudier ?

Pourquoi est-ce incorrect ?

Comment: Without getting into whether your friend’s use of “quoi” is perfectly acceptable or not, I will suggest that you might be confusing “quoi” with “qui” in your understanding that “*que* is for things” and “*qui/[quoi?]* is for people.”

Comment: To give exemples of what @PapaPoule says, you say "Qui est-ce ?" for a persone, "Qu'est-ce ?" for a thing, "C'est qui ?" for a person, and "C'est quoi ?" for a thing.

Comment: In English (& I think it’s also true in French), putting (a usually emphatic) “what” (for things) and “who” (for people) at the end of a sentence (like your friend’s French sentence) is a common way to express disbelief/disapproval in/of what has just been said: … Son: “Dad, I want to study Jedi Philosophy and marry Princess Leia”… Father: “You want to study **what** and marry **who**?”

Comment: The main problem here is assessing what **you** mean by correct and how the answer will understand **correctness**. This is definitely French and is common in spoken French. Opinions will vary about the contexts where it is welcome and the impressions it will make on your listener/reader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Tu veux étudier quoi ?* est du langage familier. Alors que *Qu'est ce que tu veux étudier ?* est du langage courant.

Comment: *Que veux-tu étudier?* ou *Que souhaites-tu étudier?* serait probablement plus approprié pour l'écriture.

Comment: This depends on context. If you want to focalize on the object to be studied, the first form would be my choice over the second and they would both be in the same register.

Comment: La première est incorrecte, la seconde correcte. Mais "qu'est-ce que" est toujours une tournure acceptée pour le langage courant mais mal considérée, peu jolie: c'est un procédé facile qui évite de gérer les inversions pour les interrogatives: est-ce que, qu'est-ce que, qui est-ce qui + relative affirmative.

Answer (score -1):

C'est correct de dire « Tu veux étudier quoi ? », c'est pas faux.

Comment: Qu'est-ce que *faux* signifie dans ce contexte ?